# Como configurar um projeto recém criado para não criar mais os arquivos spec.ts no angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, api, testes-de-unidade, component

Minha pergunta é sobre angular Já temos uma projeto em **Angular12** rotando e temos somente q dar manutenção e criar novos compoments de algumas paginas adcionadas, mas foi decidido agora que não queremos mais arquivos spec.ts pois nunca foram usado, Como evitar que o CLI crie os spec.ts nos novos compomentes ou services. Sem que precise por '''skipTests=true''' . Alguém pode dar uma help??

Comment: tente esse link [Angular 11 CLI, "ng generate" option: --skip-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242718/angular-11-cli-ng-generate-option-skip-tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode configurar o parâmetro `skipTests` direto no arquivo `angular.json` do seu projeto especificando o comando do CLI que você quer afetar. Por exemplo, para não criar arquivos de testes unitários ao executar os comandos `ng g c <meu-component>` ou `ng g s <minha-service>`, basta adicionar no arquivo `angular.json` a seguinte especificação:

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "meu-projeto": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obs.: parte do arquivo `angular.json` no exemplo acima foi ocultado. O importante é o que está dentro do `schematics`.